# Serve static content with Restify

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm trying to serve static file using Restify with no luck. I searched online including restify site and none of the solution I found so far resolve the "resource not found" error I'm getting. This is my code -

```
server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
   'directory': 'public',
   'default': 'test.csv'
}));
```

Comment: How are you requesting the file? `http://domain.com/test.csv` ?

Comment: `http://domain.com:port#/public/` or `public/test.csv`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to take a look at your folder structure. restify combines the directory and route path you specify when using serveStatic to build a file path to serve files from.

lets say your project is located in `/project/test`

and the file containing your module that starts the server with `server.listen()` is named `app.js` is located in `/project/test/lib`

and you have your public content placed in `/project/test/public`

so now you have a structure that looks like

- `/lib`

  - `app.js`
- `/public`

  - `test.csv`

the problem is that if you add a static route like this in `app.js`

```
server.get(/\/public\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
   'directory': __dirname,
   'default': 'test.csv'
}));
```

the `__dirname` variable returns `/project/test/lib`

so restify is looking for content for http://domain.com/public in `/project/test/lib/public` which has no content

you would need to move `/public` into `/lib` for this to work

if you want to keep this same folder structure you would need to do something like

```
server.get(/\/public\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
   'directory': __dirname.replace('/lib', ''),
   'default': 'test.csv'
}));
```

so that the value of `directory` is now `/project/test` and the route will look in `/project/test/public` for static content.

Answer (score -3):

If you're wanting to request resources from a public path in the URL you'd need to setup your route like so:

```
server.get(/\/public\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
   'directory': 'public',
   'default': 'test.csv'
}));
```

And you must put your files inside of a directory called public in the root of your application.

Comment: Shouldn't `'directory': 'public'` acutally point to a relative route? such as `'directory': './public'`

Comment: Still doesn't work. And I also tried with `'directory': __dirname`

Comment: `'directory'` Is where on the filesystem you're serving static files from. You definitely **do not** want directory to be set to `__dirname`. Then people can download any file, like package.json or config.js, etc.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple You are right. I didn't think of that. But I still can't get it work.

Comment: __dirname is the path that your main node app runs, if you have for example plaved your main executable in /root/lib/app.js and your static content is in /root/public/ then you will need to change __dirname to something like __dirname.replace('/lib', '') or place your public folder inside of lib

Comment: @vbranden `__dirname` is the path to the currently executing module, not just the app entry point. If your entry point is `/app/index.js`, and you require('./lib/mymodule'), the value for `__dirname` will be different inside `mymodule.js` than it is in `index.js`.

Comment: @Timothy Strimple thanks. That is what I was trying to communicate, but I worded it poorly. It still stands that using __dirname requires taking the path of the module using it with relation to the static content into consideration when serving static content in restify.